# Gulp 4 watch not working, only run one time

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-browser-sync, gulp-4

I changed from Gulp 3 to Gulp 4, but I can't get it to work.

When I run gulp and save SCSS or HTML file it creates a new file successfully. If I save again nothing happens. **It only runs ones.**

Below is my **gulpfile.js**

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

sass.compiler = require('node-sass');


gulp.task('sass', function() {
 return gulp.src('template/assets/scss/**/*.scss')
   .pipe(sass.sync({outputStyle: 'expanded'}).on('error', sass.logError))
   .pipe(gulp.dest('template/assets/css/'))
   .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});


// Static Server and watching scss/html files
gulp.task('server', gulp.series('sass', function(){
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: "./template"
        }
    });
    gulp.watch("template/assets/scss/**/*.scss", gulp.task('sass'));
    gulp.watch("template/assets/scss/**/*.scss", browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch("template/**/*.html", browserSync.reload);
}));


gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch(['sass']);
});


gulp.task('default', gulp.series(gulp.parallel('sass', 'watch', 'server')))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 'watch' task you have is unnecessary (and its syntax is wrong):

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch(['sass']);
});
```

so delete it.  You already have `gulp.watch` statements in your `'server'` task:

```
gulp.watch("template/assets/scss/**/*.scss", gulp.task('sass'));
//  gulp.watch("template/assets/scss/**/*.scss", browserSync.reload);
```

I commented out the second one above because you already call

```
.pipe(browserSync.stream());
```

at the end of the `'sass'` task so the commented out `browserSync.reload` line is duplicative as well.

You need to signal async completion in your 'server' task too, see where I added the `done` callback to do this:

```
// Static Server and watching scss/html files
gulp.task('server', function (done) {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: "./template"
        }
    });
    gulp.watch("template/assets/scss/**/*.scss", gulp.series('sass'));
    //  gulp.watch("template/assets/scss/**/*.scss", browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch("template/**/*.html", browserSync.reload);
    done();
});
```

I removed the `gulp.series('sass')` call from the beginning of the `'serve'` task  because you already call `'sass'` first in your default task so you don't need it in the `'server'` task.

Also note the use of `gulp.series('sass')` in the first watch instead of `gulp.task('sass')`.

Finally, since we are removing the separate `'watch'`  task, change the 'default' task to :

```
gulp.task('default', gulp.series('sass', 'server'));
```

and remove the `gulp.parallel` in there - you simply want `'sass'` to run before `'server'`.

Here are all the changes:

```
// Static Server and watching scss/html files
gulp.task('server', function (done) {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: "./template"
        }
    });
    gulp.watch("template/assets/scss/**/*.scss", gulp.series('sass'));
    // gulp.watch("template/assets/scss/**/*.scss", browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch("template/**/*.html", browserSync.reload);
    done();
}));


// gulp.task('watch', function() {
//    gulp.watch(['sass']);
// });

gulp.task('default', gulp.series('sass', 'server'));
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help @mark Let me try this

Comment: Thanks a lot. After lot of research I found gulp 4 watch is working.